# How do I prevent JTable's ListSelectionListener from deselecting a row by itself?

Tags: java, jtable

When I click to **select a row** in a **Jtable** the `ListSelectionListener` fire **twice** one for selecting and another for deselecting the row so the user get the impression that the row wasn't select as it occurs very quickly.

How can I prevent the row's deselection?

**PS:** The default behavior without implementing `ListSelectionListener` works as expected when the user click the row keeps selected.

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried. Provide us with a minimal, complete and verifiable example [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your Listener will get one hit for the row being deselected, and another for the row being selected.

Comment: First thank you for your quick replies. I didn't add the code because I'm getting the JTable control from the UI's form and simply adding the ListSelectionListener to it besides populating it with data setting a new AbstractTableModel. I've just tried to replicate a smaller example creating the JTable programmatically and this problem doesn't happen so it must be something is configured on UI but I didn't specify any configuration to the JTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `e.getValueIsAdjusting` if it is first event or second.

From javadoc:

> Returns whether or not this is one in a series of multiple events,
>   where changes are still being made.

Comment: Thank you. Have a nice day.